# Generate random number into text input using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to generate a random number into a text field. Unfortunately ID's are not an option here so I'm using classes as identifiers. I've tried a number of things but cannot seem to get this work.

HTML for input:

```
<div class="productAttributeRow productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText">
    <div class="productAttributeLabel">
        <label>
            <span class="name">
                Hidden:   
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="productAttributeValue">
        <input type="text" class="Field validation" value="" size="5"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)
$('#BuyThis').click(function () {
    $(".productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText.productAttributeValue input[type="
    text "]").val(randomnumber);
});
```

In the above scenario, `#BuyThis` is a button:

```
<a id="BuyThis" type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-warning" href="#product-options" data-toggle="modal">
```

However, it's not necessary this happen with a click, I just want a random number in the field before the form is submitted.

Also tried without the click:

```
$(function(){
   var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)    
   $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val( randomnumber );      

})
```

Another attempt:

```
function randomNumber(m, n) {
    m = parseInt(m);
    n = parseInt(n);
    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - m + 1)) + m;
    ('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').value = randomnumber;
});
```

Tried various other functions and combinations to no avail.

Comment: can you provide a demo of your problem.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The div with class `productAttributeValue` is inside `productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText`, so when selecting you should add a space between them:

```js
$(function() {
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)
  $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText .productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val(randomnumber);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productAttributeRow productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText">
  <div class="productAttributeLabel">
    <label>
      <span class="name">Hidden:</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="productAttributeValue">
    <input type="text" class="Field validation" value="" size="5" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Does work: http://jsfiddle.net/3hhCx/

Comment: Ha ha ha...I looked at that probably half a dozen times but doing a million things at the same time and kept forgetting to do it. Duh! Thank you thank you thank you thank you so much. I've been working on this for a lot longer than I should have been, very relieved to see it working. Thanks! ~Susan

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText.productAttributeValue')
```

Is selecting an element which has **both** `.productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText` *and* `.productAttributeValue`.

You want to select an element which has `.productAttributeValue` which is a child of `.productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText`.

To do that, add a space between them:

```
$('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText .productAttributeValue')
```

To insert a random value, use:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)    
$('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText .productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val( randomnumber );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this... 
HTML

```
<div class="productAttributeRow productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText">
    <div class="productAttributeLabel">
        <label>
            <span class="name">
                Hidden:   
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="productAttributeValue">
        <input type="text" class="Field validation" value="" size="5"  />
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)    

$('#BuyThis').click(function(){    
  $(".productAttributeConfigurableEntryNumbersOnlyText .productAttributeValue input:text").val( randomnumber ); 
});
```

try [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mz_arain08/zLTWg/)